# Javascript calculator with exponents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to create a simple calculator using html5, css3 and javascript. My problem is that my button for exponent does not seem to work, all the other operator buttons work fine. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function result(){
        btn.value = eval(btn.value);
    }
</script>
<style type = "text/css">
  .box{
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .display{
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    left:50px;
    width:310px;
    height:60px;
  }
  .display input{
    color: black;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
    left:3px;
    top:3px;
    width:295px;
    height:45px;
  }
  .key{
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    left:50px;
  }
  .button{
    width:55px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  .button.gray{
    background-color:gray;
  }
  .button.black{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "box">
    <div class = "display"><input type = "text" readonly size="20" id="btn"></div>
     <div class = "key">
    <p><input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "1" onclick="btn.value+=1">
       <input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "2" onclick="btn.value+=2">
       <input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "3" onclick="btn.value+=3">
       <input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "+" onclick="btn.value+='+'"></p>
    <p><input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "4" onclick="btn.value+=4">
       <input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "5" onclick="btn.value+=5">
       <input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "6" onclick="btn.value+=6">
       <input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "-" onclick="btn.value+='-'"></p>
    <p><input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "7" onclick="btn.value+=7">
       <input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "8" onclick="btn.value+=8">
       <input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "9" onclick="btn.value+=9">
       <input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "*" onclick="btn.value+='*'"></p>
    <p><input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "%" onclick="btn.value+='%'">
       <input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "0" onclick="btn.value+=0">
       <input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "^" onclick="btn.value+='^'">
       <input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "/" onclick="btn.value+='/'"></p>
    <p><input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "C" onclick="btn.value=''">
       <input type = "button" class = "button black" value = "=" onclick="result()";></p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you have spaces between attribute names and values?  I'd say you can't, or at least shouldn't.

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript at all. That might be the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `display.value+=1`?

What is "display"? "display" is just a variable, not your display input element.

Comment: @EliasSoares http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object however it shouldn't be used in production imo.

Comment: I am trying to get the number 1 to display by pressing the button for 1. This is my goal at the moment. Thank you for responding so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a script, like JavaScript, to handle actions performed by the Client. For the most part, HTML is only a markup language (to display data), and CSS (in `<style></style>` tags) is a way to format/design that markup. You need a script to handle actions,

HTML: onclick="call the JavaScript function(pass in the value of that button)"

```
<p><input type = "button" class = "button gray" value = "1" onclick="showNum(this.value)">
```

JS: Take the value as input, get the input box by ID (`.getElementById(your id)`), display it

```
function showNum (input) {
        var display = document.getElementById("btn");
        display.value = input; 
 }
```

Here is a working paste bin:

http://jsbin.com/xijatosate/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

just for fun - partially working calculator. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hbehzkfv/)

to make your calculator working you should include bunch of javascript code, without it wont do anything.

Catch button clicks by JQuery on method.

```
$('.box').on('click','.button',function(){
```

Answer (score -2):

Here, I fixed code for you.

```
function display(val) {
    var dis = document.getElementById("btn");
    dis.value += val;
}
```

You should start from this template. I suggest you to start your coding career at [www.w3schools.com/](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Have fun!

Full code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matox/ekthvn7o/)

Comment: link only answers are not valid, include example code

Comment: lol, you do know there's edit history, right? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26528987/revisions thank you for listening.